# ROS Electric Install "unable to locate package"

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to roll back to ROS Electric because of an error I'm receiving with Gazebo (as described here: http://answers.ros.org/question/37072/gazebo-sdf-has-no-gazebo-element/) ...or at least I think it's related to those two things.
But, in order to do that, I have to use the
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-desktop-full  command... however I'm receiving the "unable to locate package..." error.

Is Electric no longer available?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37242/ros-electric-install-%22unable-to-locate-package%22/) by [sl0w](https://answers.ros.org/users/2556/sl0w/) on ROS Answers with karma: 6 on 2012-06-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-06-25**:
Try removing ros-electric-desktop-* (or via a search in synaptic).

**Comment by [sl0w](https://answers.ros.org/users/2556/sl0w/) on 2012-06-25**:
Synaptic only has ros-fuerte listed and running ros-electric-desktop gives me the same error as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Except for that's exactly the problem, Gazebo 1.0 is throwing the error listed above in the other thread, and I've not been able to figure out how to fix it...

---

Originally posted by [sl0w](https://answers.ros.org/users/2556/sl0w/) with karma: 6 on 2012-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-06-26**:
You already got a (in my opinion) correct answer. Essentially your world file contains an error that you need to fix.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess you are using Ubuntu Precise for which only ROS Fuerte is available. [REP-0003](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) defines the supported ROS distros for the different Ubuntu versions.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-06-25**:
ROS Fuerte has Gazebo 1.0. Significantly different from earlier releases, it should hopefully be more stable for future use.